# Selenium: How to click on a link with no class or ID

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How do I click this link using Selenium in Python? I've been able to get to the webpage using Selenium and click other links that have IDs. But this one doesn't have an ID or name.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="dashboard in $ctrl.dashboards track by $index" class="btn btn-primary ng-scope active" ng-class="{active: dashboard.Dashboard_Id == $ctrl.activeDashboard.Dashboard_Id}" ng-click="$ctrl.dashboardClick(dashboard)" style="">
     <span ng-bind="dashboard.Name" class="ng-binding">Hours By Activity</span>
</div>
```

I've tried this with no luck:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Hours by Activity')]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.ng-binding[ng-bind='dashboard.Name']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ng-binding' and @ng-bind='dashboard.Name'][text()='Hours By Activity']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```